# Differences between ML Type I, and ML Type II, and full Bayesian inference?

Tags: regression, bayesian, generalized-linear-model, maximum-likelihood

Can someone please point me to a good note (or tutorial) that explains the difference between the three common types of statistical inference techniques: (a) ML Type I estimation, (b) ML Type II estimation, and (c) full Bayesian inference? A simple example using a linear regression model $y=X \beta + \eta$ (where $\eta$ is normally distributed) would suffice for understanding.

**Update**: A reference to ML Type I and Type II estimation can be found in this book [Machine Learning: A Bayesian and optimization perspective by Sergios Theodoridis](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=NHODBAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false) on pages 592 and 600. Note that, in this book these two estimators have been referred to as the MAP Type I and Type II estimators.

Comment: It would help if you could first point us towards a source that explains what "ML Type I" and "ML Type II" are.

Comment: Added a reference if that helps